# Select Case Function with Multiple Criteria is Not Looping

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors, select-case

I am new to vba and my first time working with "Select Case".  Briefly, I am trying to loop (number of rows will change from sheet to sheet) by finding the "cust_num" column header and go through each row, if the cust_num matches criteria on a particular row then "Barco" will be put into the same row under the "company name" column.

When I compile "Barco" is placed under the first row only, so appears not to be looping through each row, sample below.

```
XX278        Barco
XX004   
XX004   
XX278   
XX004   
XX004   
XX278   
XX278   





Dim Nu As Range
    Dim cmpny As Range
    Dim v As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    v = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("customer_name", LookAt:=xlPart).End(xlDown).Count - 1 
'count number of rows

    Set Nu = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("cust_num", LookAt:=xlPart) 'set Nu = cust_num column header
    Set cmpny = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("company name", LookAt:=xlPart) 'set cmpny = company name column

    For y = 0 To v 'loop through each row
            Select Case Nu.Offset(1 + y, 0).Value 'row 1 + y of "cust_num"
            Case "XX004", "XX278", "XX318" 'if "cust_num" row = these #'s
                 cmpny.Offset(1 + y, 0).Value = "Barco" 'Then corresponding row under "company name" column = "Varco"
            End Select
    Next
```

Comment: `Select Case Nu.Offset(...`

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams that fixed the error.  When I run the macro it's putting "Barco" in the first row that matches the cust_num, but doesn't seem to be looping through any other rows.  I tried to put the set ranges inside the For loop but that didn't seem to work.  Any ideas?  Thanks again!

Comment: Can you update your question with the current code?

Comment: Sure, I have updated the question and included the current code.  Thanks for taking a look, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems there: have you tried setting a breakpoint in the loop to check it's seeing the values you expect? It's possible that (eg) your company numbers have extra spaces or something along those lines. Add some `debug.print` statements so you can check your assumptions about (eg) the value of `v`

Comment: Great, thanks for the advice.  The row count was not accurate, so just made a change and that fixed the issue.  Now that I know how to debug that will likely eliminate my basic questions, hopefully:).  Since I'm new to stackoverflow, can you advise on how I should finalize this question, ie mark it as answered?

Comment: You can post an answer yourself and accept it: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

With @TimWilliams help my code now works.  This uses the Select Case function to loop through specified rows and determines if the criteria has been satisifed for that cell, if so a name is inserted on the same row to the right of the criteria cell (in this case the cust_num).

```
Dim Nu As Range
Dim cmpny As Range
Dim v As Integer
Dim y As Integer

v = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'count number of rows 
'count number of rows

Set Nu = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("cust_num", LookAt:=xlPart) 'set Nu = cust_num column header
Set cmpny = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("company name", LookAt:=xlPart) 'set cmpny = company name column

For y = 0 To v 'loop through each row
        Select Case Nu.Offset(1 + y, 0).Value 'row 1 + y of "cust_num"
        Case "XX004", "XX278", "XX318" 'if "cust_num" row = these #'s
             cmpny.Offset(1 + y, 0).Value = "Barco" 'Then corresponding row under "company name" column = "Varco"
        End Select
Next
```